# How to get rid of "Can't set headers after they are sent." error

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I'm creating a little API for my project and I'm having problem getting documents saved in my MongoDB database.

```
postRouter.get('/get/:skip/:limit', (req, res) => {
  const {skip, limit} = req.params;
  const query = Post.find().skip(skip).limit(limit).sort('-date');

  query.exec((err, docs) => {
    if (err) {
      res.send({error: 'Something went wrong'});
    }
    res.json(docs);
  });
});
```

Every time I make a GET request I get "Can't set headers after they are sent.". How can I fix my code?

Comment: inside the if conditional statement do `return res.send({error: "balbalba"})` .

Comment: Thanks, now it works :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After executing res.send(), you need to make sure this is the last thing you'll send to the client.

```
postRouter.get('/get/:skip/:limit', (req, res) => {
  const {skip, limit} = req.params;
  const query = Post.find().skip(skip).limit(limit).sort('-date');

  query.exec((err, docs) => {
    if (err) {
      return res.send({error: 'Something went wrong'});
    }
    res.json(docs);
  });
});
```

Or

```
postRouter.get('/get/:skip/:limit', (req, res) => {
  const {skip, limit} = req.params;
  const query = Post.find().skip(skip).limit(limit).sort('-date');

  query.exec((err, docs) => {
    if (err) {
      res.send({error: 'Something went wrong'});
    }else{
      res.json(docs);
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

the problem seems to be here:

```
    if (err) {
      res.send({error: 'Something went wrong'});
    }
    res.json(docs);
```

when err is trueish it will send back the error and then fall out the if and do res.json() too.

do

```js
    if (err) {
      return res.send({error: 'Something went wrong'});
    }
    return res.json(docs);
```

but now you need to find out why err is not undefined in the first place :)